# Android: Sending data to server by JSONObject over post method

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

This question may be a duplicate but i couldn't find any solution in the questions.

It is a simple login method.

Basicly i am taking two parameters from the user and send them to the server, the server searches the database and return the result which matches the parameters that i send. And if there is no matching result than the method simply returns null so i can ask the user to correct the user name and the password.

Here is the code that i use to send the parameters;

```
    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(0,new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
        dataToSend.add(1,new BasicNameValuePair("password",user.password));



        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.okanyakit.com/tez/FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if (jObject.length() == 0){
                returnedUser = null;
            }else {

                String username = jObject.getString("username");
                String password = jObject.getString("password");
                String email = jObject.getString("email");
                String  phonenumber = jObject.getString("phonenumber");
                String bloodtype = jObject.getString("bloodtype");
                String  birthday = jObject.getString("birthday");
                String address = jObject.getString("address");


                returnedUser = new User(username,password,email,phonenumber,bloodtype,birthday,address);

            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return returnedUser;
    }
```

In here i am able to put both of the username and password to the list, but when it connects to the server i get an error and it says i sent only one parameter while it was expecting two.

I don't think there is a problem with my php code but i am not sure, so here it is ;

```
    <?php   
$con=mysqli_connect("89.19.30.210","okan_tez","okan_tez","okan_tez_andro");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];




mysqli_close($con);
$statement = mysqli_prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss",$username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userid, $username, $password, $email, $phonenumber, $bloodtype, $birthday, $address);

$user = array();
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user [username] = $username;
    $user [password] = $password;
    $user [email] = $email;
    $user [phonenumber] = $phonenumber;
    $user [bloodtype] = $bloodtype;
    $user [birthday] = $birthday;
    $user [address] = $address;

}
echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);


?>
```

And here is the debug screenshot ;

[image]

here is what is says in green font

**Warning**:  mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **11**

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **12**

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **13**

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **14**

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **15**

**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **18**
[]
**Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home/okanyakit.com/httpdocs/tez/FetchUserData.php** on line **29**

So what is the problem and how can i solve it ? Please the project deadline is in two days and i have lots of more problems. And i have a similiar problem with the registering part. I think if i can solve this i will be able to solve that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't close the connection here :

```
mysqli_close($con);
$statement = mysqli_prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
```

And `mysqli_prepare` needs `$con` argument (http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php) :

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
```

Comment: Thank you so much this may be most basic mistake i have ever made. Thank you again :D